# Overlapping one cell on other with z-index seems to not work

Tags: cell, z-index, overlapping

Im trying to give "box2" a bigger z-index value than the other boxes, in order to make the box2 overlap the other(for instance on box number 5 that next to it), but everytime im trying this, the boxes are "running away" and opening a new  column. **i did that on codeopen so the if it makes any different:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
   z-index: 10;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  color: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 100px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column: 3 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

link to codeopen: https://codepen.io/Tsuri/pen/dyZbdGJ

Comment: grid-auto-flow will not place items in occupied cells. 
Changing the z-index does not change the x y position.

Comment: If you have a fixed amount of boxes you can manually position each one where you want. If it's a dynamic amount can you give a more concrete realistic example?

Comment: Thanks Arye, here is my codeopen:
https://codepen.io/Tsuri/pen/RwjbQrJ
i only try for practice to ovelap box2 on 9

Comment: You can try using negetive margins https://codepen.io/arye-dov-eidelman/pen/YzEKOdx